# MySQL: How to insert all columns from table to new table and NULL for extra columns not matched?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let me explain

- I have a MySQL table [Table A] with `89 Columns` and `5 Million` rows.
- I have to add `10 new columns`(default `NULL`) to [Table A]. Currently performing Alter Statement on [Table A] take more than 2 hours.
- I copied the DDL structure from [Table A] to [copied_Table A] as

  `CREATE TABLE copied_table_a LIKE table_a;`
- The I added `10 columns` to `copied_table_a`.
- Now I want to insert all data from `table_a` to `copied_table_a` as

  `mysql> INSERT copied_table_a SELECT * FROM table_a;                                                                                                                                   ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

**Question**
- What is the best way to get data now to `copied_table_a`?

Comment: without explicitly stating the original 89 columns you mean?

Comment: Sorry, Yes. That is what I mean

Comment: Is there any reason, other than typing, that you don't want to list out the columns explicitly? _Because many db management applications, such as MySQL Workbench, can create a select query for you to start from with all fields listed._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you list all columns, but you can do:

```
INSERT INTO copied_table_a
    SELECT a.*,
           NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
           NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    FROM table_a;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick way to save typing you could make use of the `information_schema.columns` table :

```
select concat("insert into copied_table_a (",
               group_concat(column_name),
               ") select ",
               group_concat(column_name)," from ",table_name)
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'table_a';
```

To generate the SQL for you. Only really good for a one-off but quite fun to play around with.